# Can't get fbq to trigger a view content on the vehicle content type

Tags: javascript, facebook

There are a few questions related to `fbq(‘track’, ‘ViewContent’)` on here but none talk about the `vehicle` content_type.

```
fbq(‘track’, ‘ViewContent’, {
  content_ids: [‘000018’],
  content_type: ‘vehicle’
});
```

I put that on my site in `<script>` tags and also tried it in console.

Error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Any idea what's wrong with the syntax? Even if I add a comma on line 3, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe is those  quotes´´ replace them with ''

Comment: @JavierRojas Wow I really feel like a noob.